# XAMPP + mod_wsgi + python Windows 7

Tags: python, django, apache, xampp, mod-wsgi

i'm trying to install django on a local test server [i know python+django has one] and i've already set up xampp hosting:

Apache 2.4, Python 2.7, mod_wsgi (compiled from source: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows and using win32-ap22py27.mk, idk if the make file I used is okay since there are no errors upon starting apache and apache says it loads the wsgi module as well as my python)

[image: xampp]

**wsgi.conf [that is included in httpd.conf]:**

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi "C:/xampp/htdocs/wsgi/scripts/test.wsgi"
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/wsgi/scripts">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**and a generic test.wsgi file:**

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response("200 OK", [])
    output = "<html>Hello World! Request: %s</html>"
    output %= env['PATH_INFO']
    return [output]
```

My problem is that I get an aborted connection on testing a wsgi app: `**http://localhost/wsgi**`

i've searched the internets and no luck

Answer (score 4):

okay there must be something wrong with the make file and so therfore module
here if anyone interested(bookmark this thing):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi

using apache2.4 and python2.7 compatible mod_wsgi3.4  and now it works...

Answer (score 0):

```
This topic is useful for Windows 10, xampp webserver as well.
I was struggling to find precompiled mod_wsgi.so for 
Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) 
Python/2.7.13 
This [link][1] is useful to find the appropriate version of mod_wsgi.
IF you are lucky, you can find the precompiled version [here][1]
There is a step by step guidance available [here][1]

    enter code here

  [1]: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst
  [2]: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi
  [3]: https://everything2.com/title/Installing+Python+on+XAMPP
```

Comment: The recommend method is to build it yourself by running ``pip install mod_wsgi``. See PyPi page for mod_wsgi.